# Sending Information Back From Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

A user clicks on edit on the index.jsp page and it sends them to a editCustomer.jsp page.  The problem is when I click update it doesnt update the customer information on the index page.

How can I do this using the code I have?

### INDEX.JSP

```
    <%@page import="edu.witc.Assignment02.controller.CustomerServlet"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
           <% String customerString ="";
           ArrayList<edu.witc.Assignment02.model.Customer> customers = (java.util.ArrayList)request.getAttribute("customers");
           for (edu.witc.Assignment02.model.Customer customer : customers) {
                customerString += "<li>" + customer.getName() +
                           "(" + customer.getCity() + ") (" +
                           "<a href='editCustomer?id=" + customer.getId() +
                           "'>edit</a>)</li>";
           }%>
           <%=customerString %>
           </ul>
           <body>
</html>
```

### EDITCUSTOMER.JSP

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import="edu.witc.Assignment02.controller.CustomerServlet"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Edit Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Edit Customer</h2> 
<% int customerId = 
                    Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));%>
 <form method='post' action='customer'>
  <input type='hidden' name ='id' value='<%=customerId%>'/>
  <table>

  <tr><td>Name:</td><td>"
 <input name='name' /> 
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td>City:</td><td>
<input name='city' />
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2' style='text-align:right'>
<input type='submit' value='Update'/></td> 
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'>
<a href='customer'>Customer List</a>
</td></tr>
  </table>
            </form></body>


</html>
```

### SERVLET

```
package edu.witc.Assignment02.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import edu.witc.Assignment02.*;
import edu.witc.Assignment02.model.Customer;

/*
 * Not thread-safe. For illustration purpose only
 */
@WebServlet(name = "CustomerServlet", urlPatterns = { 
        "/customer", "/editCustomer", "/updateCustomer"})
public class CustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -20L;

    private List<edu.witc.Assignment02.model.Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        Customer customer1 = new Customer();
        customer1.setId(1);
        customer1.setName("Donald D.");
        customer1.setCity("Miami");
        customers.add(customer1);

        Customer customer2 = new Customer();
        customer2.setId(2);
        customer2.setName("Mickey M.");
        customer2.setCity("Orlando");
        customers.add(customer2);       
    }

    private void sendCustomerList(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)//redirect to index
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String url = "/index.jsp";
        request.setAttribute("customers", customers);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);




    }

    private Customer getCustomer(int customerId) {
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            if (customer.getId() == customerId) {
                return customer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void sendEditCustomerForm(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String url = "/editCustomer.jsp";
        request.setAttribute("customers", customers);

        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
    }


    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        if (uri.endsWith("/customer")) {
            sendCustomerList(response, request);
        } else if (uri.endsWith("/editCustomer")) {
            sendEditCustomerForm(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, ServletException {
        // update customer
        int customerId = 0;
        try {
            customerId = 
                    Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        Customer customer = getCustomer(customerId);
        if (customer != null) {
            customer.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
            customer.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));
        }
        sendCustomerList(response, request);
    }
}
```

### CUSTOMER.JAVA

```
package edu.witc.Assignment02.model;

public class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String city;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever you do, **do not use scriptlets.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expect to happen. You are submitting this form

```
<form method='get' action='customer'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
                "
                <input name='name' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City:</td>
            <td>
                <input name='city' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' style='text-align:right'>
                <input type='submit' value='Update' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <a href='customer'>Customer List</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And handling it with

```
if (uri.endsWith("/customer")) {
     sendCustomerList(response, request);
```

and

```
private void sendCustomerList(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)//redirect to index
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    String url = "/index.jsp";
    request.setAttribute("customers", customers);
    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
}
```

Nothing in the code above modifies anything in the `customers` `List`. Objects don't get changed on their own. You have to make the modifications yourself.

Maybe you meant to submit the form with a `POST` request. In that case, you would need an `<input>` field for the `id`.

---

Think about the request-response cycle.

Your Servlet container receives an HTTP request, it dispatches your Servlet to handle it. Your servlet performs some logic and forwards to a JSP. The JSP renders some HTML which is written to the body of the HTTP response. The response is sent to the client. In this case, your client is a browser which reads the HTML text and renders it graphically. You can then interact with it, fill in input fields and click buttons. When you do this, the browser takes the values you've entered and produces an HTTP request which it sends to your server. And so on, and so on...

Comment: could it be a hidden field?

Comment: @user2939808 Absolutely. But don't you want the user to choose which?

Comment: no when i click edit it send me to the form IE editcustomer and has the id in the url for whichever user it is.  Now i need to just get the info to update and when it redirects to the index page. I added a hidden field(see code) and nothing happens same as before

Comment: @user2939808 You didn't give it a value.

Comment: in the servlet I do though. This is where I am stuck i guess.

Comment: @user2939808 You need to set it as an attribute in your servlet. You can then retrieve it in your JSP with Expression Language so that you can set it as the value of the `<input>`. Something like `value="${id}"`.

Comment: Ok see above for how I got it to work.  The one thing I dont get is i did the same thing in the servlet under the post. Why doesnt it work by just going to the post method?

Comment: @user2939808 Read my edit, see if it clears anything up. What you do in your post and what you do in your JSP are completely separate. One is getting the value, one is writing the value.